# Problem with passing parameters and scopes, how can I fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a password generator and strength checker (I'm new to coding), and my problem is that I can't get a function working that generates a password, calls the function that checks the strength, and have the strength checking function return back to the generating function.

Sorry if that was a bad explanation, please check the code for clarification.

Everything I've tried has partially worked or not worked at all, including using globals; even then I couldn't get it functioning properly.

```
import random
allchars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!$%^&*()_-=+"
def generatePassword():
    generatedPass = ""
    while points < 20:
        for i in range(random.randint(8, 12)):
            generatedPass += random.choice(allchars)
        checkFunc(generatedPass)
    points = 0

    print(generatedPass)


def checkFunc(password):
    numberofTriples = 0
    consecChars = []
    points = 0
    allCrit = 0
    (Redacted code that just calculates the points of the password)
    (Redacted code that just calculates the points of the password)
    return points
```

I want it to take the password it randomly generates, and check its strength, if it falls under a certain point threshold, to generate another until it is above the threshold, and print it.

Comment: Hi Anss M, does this code run? IINM you check the value of `points` prior to initializing it in your `generatePassword` func

Comment: I forgot to add, points is already set to 0 outside of a function in the program.

Comment: Your question doesn't actually contain any question or an error to help you with, so I'm not sure how we can help you. It would be good if you check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `generatedPassword` function doesn't ever set the value of `points` in the `while` loop, thus it is never failing the condition of `points < 20`.

You'd want to change `checkFunc(generatedPass)` to `points = checkFunc(generatedPass)`. This will properly set the value of points, and break from the loop.

Answer (score 1):

So here are couple issues with your code:

```
import random
allchars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!$%^&*()_-=+"
def generatePassword():
    #note you should have initiated ***points*** to 0 before using it in your while loop
    generatedPass = ""
    while points < 20:
        for i in range(random.randint(8, 12)):
            generatedPass += random.choice(allchars)
        checkFunc(generatedPass)
    points = 0 #points here has no value assignment you want to assign checkFunc()'s return value to points like this:   points = checkFunc(generatedPass), or else you'll have an infinite loop. 

    print(generatedPass)


def checkFunc(password):
    numberofTriples = 0
    consecChars = []
    points = 0
    allCrit = 0
##    (Redacted code that just calculates the points of the password)
##    (Redacted code that just calculates the points of the password)

     #Just be sure you have points variable here being updated according to the strength before you return it.
```

Here is an example of the same code but instead of strength, we are checking length:

```
import random
allchars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!$%^&*()_-=+"
def generatePassword():
    generatedPass = ""
    points = 0 
    while points < 20:
        for i in range(random.randint(8, 12)):
            generatedPass += random.choice(allchars)
        points = checkLength(generatedPass)


    print(generatedPass)


def checkLength(password):

    return len(password)
```

Input:

> > > generatePassword()

Output:

> > > 1Aid0%7tZYo0Ip(u_zeCQo=I

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing great.

Here is a corrected code that should work:

Corrections done:

- `points` was not declared before usage
- `points` were not updated after call of checkFunc

N.B: to simulate the computing of the score, I used the random function.

Here is the full code:

```
import random
allchars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!$%^&*()_-=+"


def generatePassword():
    generatedPass = ""
    # We set points to 0 to start the while loop
    points = 0
    while points < 20:
        for i in range(random.randint(8, 12)):
            generatedPass += random.choice(allchars)
        # We set points to the score computed by checkFunc to know if we need to trigger the generation of a new password.
        points = checkFunc(generatedPass)

    print(generatedPass)


def checkFunc(password):
    numberofTriples = 0
    consecChars = []
    points = 0
    allCrit = 0
    # Simulating point computation
    points = random.randint(10,30)
    return points
```

I hope it helps, 
Have a lovely day,

G